# Perl Positive lookahead

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to match the lines between two #SEGMENT tags in Perl, with the following regex, without success. The regex is working in Notepad++, cannot seem to get it to work in perl. What could be the problem?

```
            foreach $line (@lines) {

       if($line =~ m/(?<=#SEGMENT)[\w\W]*?(?=(#SEGMENT)|(x y z))/){
            print $line;
               } 
            }

        #SEGMENT 18 3.5 3.5  - - 0.0 0.0
        #TEST SEGPOS 0 0 lat=48.14066827297211 lon=11.681677401065826 lat=48.140748739242554 lon=11.682549118995667
        #TEST LnWidthR 0 65 Index=0 TotalLanesRight=1 Width=3.5 Type=1 Description=DRIVING
        #TEST LnWidthL 0 65 Index=0 TotalLanesLeft=1 Width=3.5 Type=1 Description=DRIVING
        #SEGMENT 16 3.5 3.5  - - 0.0 0.0
        #TEST Points 0 0 x=-66.69588384218514 y=-104.09948819875717 z=0.0 curvature=0.0
        #TEST LnWidthR 0 16 Index=0 TotalLanesRight=1 Width=3.5 Type=1 Description=DRIVING
        #TEST LnWidthL 0 16 Index=0 TotalLanesLeft=1 Width=3.5 Type=1 Description=DRIVING
        #SEGMENT 90 3.5 3.5  - - 0.0 0.0
        #TEST SEGPOS 0 0 lat=48.140738010406494 lon=11.682769060134888 lat=48.140649497509 lon=11.683978736400604
        #TEST Points 0 0 x=11.168571664951742 y=192.30218220874667 z=0.0 curvature=0.0
        #TEST Points 0 0 x=11.305719518102705 y=225.70159672945738 z=0.0 curvature=0.0
        #TEST LnWidthR 0 90 Index=0 TotalLanesRight=1 Width=3.5 Type=1 Description=DRIVING
        #TEST LnWidthL 0 90 Index=0 TotalLanesLeft=1 Width=3.5 Type=1 Description=DRIVING
                    #TEST LnWidthL 0 90 Index=0 TotalLanesLeft=1 Width=3.5 Type=1 Description=DRIVING
```

Comment: The problem is that your regex is being applied one line at a time, while notepad does it for the whole text. Try using the regex on the file instead of using `@lines` and a foreach loop. Warning though, this might hit the performance if the file is big.

Comment: I'd suggest that you loop through the lines and pull out the lines between `#SEGMENT` instead of using look-ahead.

Comment: `[\w\W]` ? Is that subtly different from `.` ?

Comment: to my understanding, [\w\W] and . are the same thing. I expanded from a previous initial regular exp which only contained alphanumerics at that match, which is why I didn't write . in the first place.

Comment: @JimDavis: `[\w\W]` matches any character, while `.` matches any character except newline `"\n"` unless the `/s` modifier is used on the regex. So `/[\w\W]/` and `/./s` are identical. You often see `[\s\S]` used in JavaScript, which has no option to modify the behaviour of `.`.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is applying the pattern match to each line individually. There are no lines with a substring that is both preceded and followed by `#SEGMENT` so your code produces nothing.

I suggest you write something like this. This program expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line, and prints the output to `STDOUT`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @tests;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  if (/^#SEGMENT/) {
    if (@tests) {
      print "$_\n" for @tests;
      print "---\n";
    }
    @tests = ();
  }
  else {
    push @tests, $_;
  }
}
```

**output**

```
#TEST SEGPOS 0 0 lat=48.14066827297211 lon=11.681677401065826 lat=48.140748739242554 lon=11.682549118995667
#TEST LnWidthR 0 65 Index=0 TotalLanesRight=1 Width=3.5 Type=1 Description=DRIVING
#TEST LnWidthL 0 65 Index=0 TotalLanesLeft=1 Width=3.5 Type=1 Description=DRIVING
---
#TEST Points 0 0 x=-66.69588384218514 y=-104.09948819875717 z=0.0 curvature=0.0
#TEST LnWidthR 0 16 Index=0 TotalLanesRight=1 Width=3.5 Type=1 Description=DRIVING
#TEST LnWidthL 0 16 Index=0 TotalLanesLeft=1 Width=3.5 Type=1 Description=DRIVING
---
```

Tool completed successfully

Comment: Thank you Borodin. Your answer was helpful to me. I am still looking for an answer as to how to use perl for lookahead when reading from a file..

Comment: It has been explained that you can't use lookahead if you are reading the file line by line, because you can't match against text that hasn't yet been read.

Comment: There may still be a workaround somehow which is why I'll let this question unanswered.

Comment: There is a way if you read the entire file into memory at once, but why do you insist on using a lookahead?

Comment: I tried with $lines = @lines; and ran the lookahead/lookback on it, I still couldn't get it to work..